# How to use RPC query in JavaScript with search method in Odoo 11 / 12?

Tags: javascript, odoo, rpc, odoo-11

I have following code:

```
odoo.define('module_name.templates', function(require){
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
    var rpc = require('web.rpc');

    $('#query').click(getProductBySKU);
    function getProductBySKU(){
        var domain = [];
        var args = [domain];

        var res = rpc.query({
            model: 'product.template',
            method: 'search',
            args: args
        }).then(function (products) {
            console.log(product); });
        };
    });
});
```

With that code it gives me Array of numbers, e.x. [1,2]. Length of array is equal to number of entries I have, but no objects at all. If I replace the domain with something like [('id', '=', 2)] I get error "Int object is not subscriptable".

**So my question**: is it possible to get list of objects from database with search method or at least get the fields from specified DB entries.

I also tried with search_read method. Like this:

```
odoo.define('shift_knob.templates', function(require){
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
    var rpc = require('web.rpc');

    $('#query').click(getProductBySKU);
    function getProductBySKU(){
        console.log("Hello world!");
        var domain = [('id', '=', 2)];
        var args = [domain];

        var res = rpc.query({
            model: 'product.template',
            method: 'search_read',
            args: [[], ['name', 'default_code']]
            /* args: args */
        }).then(function (products) {
            console.log(products); });
        };
    });
});
```

I get the list of objects with name, default code, but I can use only id as identificator and not the fields I want

Comment: You want to take data for particular id. Is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
[('id', '=', 2)];
```

To

```
[ ['id', '=', 2], [] ];
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation on this?